# Why does not console accept reverse line feed?

Tags: linux, assembly, console, escaping, nasm

So, I want to create a game of life simulator on the console. For that, I need to move the cursor up so I can rewrite on it and I can do that with \u008d.

I try that on the console:

```
echo -e "Everyone\n\u008dHi"
```

This gives me the result:

```
Hieryone
```

This is the expected result, and proves that my console accepts that character. But, when I try the exact same thing in NASM,

```
  global _start

  segment .text

_start:
  ;; Print message
  mov   rax, 1
  mov   rdi, 1
  mov   rsi, message
  mov   rdx, length
  syscall

  ;; Exit
  mov   rax, 60
  mov   rdi, 0
  syscall

  segment .data
message: db "Everyone", 0xa, 0x8d, "Hi"
length:  equ $ - message
```

And run it like,

```
nasm example.asm -f elf64 -o output.o
ld output.o -o output
./output
```

I get,

```
Everyone
�Hi
```

Why is that? Is there something that changes the way this character is interpreted in my NASM program? Am I missing something in the Unicode? Or is there another alternative that would allow me to move the cursor back? Any help would be useful. (I am on Linux btw)

Comment: Your terminal likely has an UTF-8 based locale.  Try `0xc2, 0x8d`.

Comment: Terminology / tags: Are you actually running this on a text [console] (ctrl+alt+f2 or whatever), not in a [terminal] window under a GUI like X11?  The X server is running on a console, but xterm / gnome-terminal / konsole are all terminals running in X11 (or wayland) windows.

Comment: Next time I apply for a job I'll put this on my rÃ©sumÃ©.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you compare it with the **hexdump**.

```
$ echo -e "Everyone\n\u008dHi" | hexdump -C
00000000  45 76 65 72 79 6f 6e 65  0a c2 8d 48 69 0a        |Everyone...Hi.|
0000000e

$ ./output | hexdump -C
00000000  45 76 65 72 79 6f 6e 65  0a 8d 48 69              |Everyone..Hi|
0000000c
```

As you see, the difference is whether you have `0xc2` or not (except for newline `0x0a`).
In UTF-8, `0x8d` must be represented as `0xc2 0x8d`.

Therefore, the following modifications will give the expected results.

```
message: db "Everyone", 0xa, 0xc2, 0x8d, "Hi"
```